# Automorphisms of infinite cyclotomic extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Denote $s_n$ be the $n^{th}$ root of unity. Let $K=\Bbb Q(s_1, s_2, s_3,\dots)$.

Then how to prove that $\operatorname{Aut}(K/\Bbb Q)$ is abelian?

Comment: $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ for some $m$

Comment: I don't think so, because K contains s_17, s_19, s_23, ...

Comment: $K$ is actually the largest abelian extension of $\mathbb Q$. That's the [Kronecker–Weber theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker–Weber_theorem).

Comment: The question is discussed [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwintIry9ZbRAhVIOlAKHcLTAjoQFghTMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp%2Fpreprint%2Ffile%2FRIMS1504.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGUurM4heI3teEBtFsh64tHIrY58w&sig2=o4s1YSn0AuOkC5pvuXhgng). Take $k_0=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The answer is probably that the inverse limit of abelian groups is abelian.

Comment: I didn't get it contained all the roots of unity. Then yes the field is the "roots of unity" closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, and its Galois group is the inverse limit of those cyclic Galois groups, so it is locally cyclic and abelian.

Comment: Do you have any elementary proof without using inverse limit?...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142236, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191897/, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148660, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104004, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265310, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884256/

Comment: The compositum of any family of abelian extensions is abelian. That’s not hard to show as a direct application of the definitions. No inverse limits need apply..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really the definition. Your field is $K = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n!})$ the limit of a tower of fields extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{(n+1)!})/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n!})$

- if $\sigma,\sigma_2  \in Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ then $\sigma(\zeta_{n!}) = \zeta_{n!}^{k(n)},\sigma_2(\zeta_{n!}) = \zeta_{n!}^{l(n)}$ where $gcd(n!,k(n))=gcd(n!,l(n))=1$ and so $$\sigma \circ \sigma_2(\zeta_{n!}) = \sigma(\zeta_{n!}^{l(n)})=\zeta_{n!}^{l(n)k(n)}=\sigma_2 \circ \sigma(\zeta_{n!})$$
- any element of $K$ can be written as $\sum_{m=0}^{n!} c_m \zeta_{n!}^m$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}, c_m\in \mathbb{Q}$
- by definition of the Galois group $\sigma \circ \sigma_2$ and $\sigma_2 \circ \sigma$ are elements of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$

i.e. 
$$\sigma \circ \sigma_2(\sum_{m=0}^{n!} c_m \zeta_{n!}^m) = \sum_{m=0}^{n!} c_m\sigma \circ \sigma_2(\zeta_{n!}^m)=\sum_{m=0}^{n!}c_m\sigma_2 \circ \sigma(\zeta_{n!}^m)=\sigma_2 \circ \sigma(\sum_{m=0}^{ n!} c_m \zeta_{n!}^m)$$
$\implies$ $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian.